# How to do MySQL + Substring? + replace?

Tags: mysql

- I am not very good with SQL and would like to be able to become better.
- I am having some trouble trying to preform a certain table manipulation.
- I would like to be able to select the substring out of the ProgUID column below

something like...

```
SUBSTRING(table.ProgUID,3,12);
```

which would give me CAMVE-9701 for the ProgUID P-CAMVE-9701-1 (removing the P- from the beginning and the -1 from the end), and then insert the substring into that rows UID.

I assume this should be fairly easy, and I have been trying to figure it out but havent had much luck.

If there is a better approach please let me know!

Thanks in advance for your thoughts / help!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE tableName
   SET UID = SUBSTRING(ProgUID,3,12)
```

- [**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f45d2/1)

Answer (score 2):

If the portion you want is always 12 characters, then

```
UPDATE table
SET UID = SUBSTRING(ProgUID, 3, 12)
```

otherwise

```
UPDATE table
SET UID = SUBSTRING(ProgUID, 3, LENGTH(ProgUID)-2)
```