# MySQL: How to UPDATE a 12 character data in the field trimming it into a 6 character of the same data?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called product and I have about hundreds of 12 character data in one column/field called product_ID. I want it trimmed into 6 character data using the same data.

I tried the below SQL but it seems like it's not working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

SQL:

```
UPDATE product
SET product_ID = SUBSTRING(product.product_ID,1,6) 
WHERE length(product_ID) > 6
```

See below example:

Current Data:

```
Product_ID
AAAAAA-00001
AAAAAA-00002
AAAAAA-00003
BBBBBB-00001
BBBBBB-00002
BBBBBB-00003
```

Target Data:

```
Product_ID
AAAAAA
AAAAAA
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
BBBBBB
BBBBBB
```

Comment: Oppss.  Sorry guys for the trouble.  I think by simply formulating this question and making it understandable to people who wanted to answer this question, gave an idea that the example solution I did was unknowingly working for me.  Cheers!

Comment: There are plenty of potential duplicates of this question (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13197400/1446005). Please delete this.